# Переключение раскладки Linux

Tags: linux, клавиатура, layout, mate

Есть 2 раскладки с языками- русская и английская. Обычно в настройках должна быть указана комбинация клавиш, по которым происходит переключение между этими 2 языками, но ее нет. А это мне как раз и нужно , потому что каждый раз лазить отдельно неудобно.Возможно это делается через командную строку, раз GUI не предоставляет

Среда  MATE

Comment: Ничего не понятно, о каких горячих клавишах речь, что значит невозможно, что именно поправить и почему именно через командную строку?

Comment: Есть 2 раскладки с языками- русская и английская. 
Обычно в настройках должна быть указана комбинация клавиш, по которым происходит переключение между этими 2 языками, но ее нет. А это мне как раз и нужно , потому что каждый раз лазить отдельно неудобно. Возможно это делается через командную строку, раз GUI не предоставляет

Comment: Что значит ее нет? В MATE горячие клавиши настраиваются точно так же, как и в GNOME или KDE — в настройках клавиатуры, в параметрах раскладок https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ykhe.png

Comment: Проверьте почту

Comment: Почему бы не прикрепить картинку прямо в текст вопроса? Вот полистайте то окно, скриншот которого вы мне прислали, и там будут горячие клавиши

Comment: Так в этом и проблема. Я пробовал уже

Comment: Не похоже, что вы пробовали, потому что скриншот с горячими клавишами вы не показали, вот вам на английском тогда https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dpzpq.png

Comment: Надо внимательнее было отнестись к этому . Вам спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все решается действительно не через командную строку. Надо быть внимательнее и найти вкладку переключения (switching to another layout)
system-preferences-software-keyboard-layouts- вкладка switching to another layout: выбор удобной вам комбинации

Answer (score -1):

Комбинация клавиш WIN + пробел

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]